# How to edit the html code of a browser element with selenium in python

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to edit html code of a browser element but I can't find a single way to do it in selenium. If anyone knows how to edit it. Please feel free to share!

Comment: why do you want to do it? You can always use `javascript` for this in `selenium`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `execute_script`

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("element xpath")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('attribute','value')",element)
```